# Use of different disc drives for Operating Systems

Tags: fedora, windows

I have a desktop with Windows on it and am wanting to install Fedora on one of the other disc drives I have due to room on the current C drive which is a 60GB SSD.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can install fedora on another hdd. During the installation you just have to select the good hard drive. Grub will probably detect your windows installation and add an entry to the grub config. In the case that your windows installation is not detected, you will be able to add a new entry to your grub configuration.

Here is the fedora [installation guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Installation_Guide/index.html) where you will find all the necessary informations to install fedora.